# Can you skip the launcher?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you Start Skyrim 'silent' without the launcher showing up?

Answer (score 7):

Install [SKSE](http://skse.silverlock.org) and run skse_launcher.exe instead of launching the game via Steam.

If that fails (for some unfathomable reason, it's been tested to work), try [this mod](http://nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50221) (has the added benefit of adding proper windowed mode support and a hotkey for switching between windowed and fullscreen modes).

Comment: Starting game via Steam == starting launcher

Comment: @spyder That's probably why the answer says not to do that.

Comment: @TZHX "or starting the game via Steam" causes launcher showing up anyway

Comment: "instead of launching SkyrimLaunder.exe or starting the game via Steam", meaning run TESV.exe instead of X or Y. It's a little ambiguous, yes, but still correct.

Comment: I'd recommend getting SKSE too and running that, it will improve your performance.

Comment: @TZHX oh, my bad.

Comment: Doesn't work launcher still shows up...

Comment: @Andalur what exactly are you doing?

Comment: @kotekzot running tesv.exe directly

Comment: @Andalur try installing SKSE ( http://skse.silverlock.org/ ) and running the executables that come with it instead. If that fails, try this mod http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50221/